# How to properly get distinct values with Mongoose in large dataset with date filters with timezone?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, fastify

I have a large MongoDB dataset of around 34gb and I am using Fastify and Mongoose for the API. I want to retrieve all list of unique userUuid from the date range. I tried the distinct method from Mongoose:

These are my filters:

```
    let filters = {
      applicationUuid: opts.applicationUuid,
      impressions: {
        $gte: opts.impressions
      },
      date: {
        $gte: moment(opts.startDate).tz('America/Chicago').format(),
        $lt: moment(opts.endDate).tz('America/Chicago').format()
      }
  }
```

This is my distinct Mongoose function:

```
return await Model.distinct("userUuid", filters)
```

This method will return an array with unique userUuid based from the filters.

This works fine for small dataset, but it has a memory cap of 16MB when it comes to huge dataset.

Therefore, I tried the aggregate method to achieve similar results, having read that it is better optimized. Nevertheless, the same filters object above does not work inside the match pipeline because aggregate does not accept string date that comes as the result of moment; but only JavaScript Date is accepted. However, JavaScript date dissregards all the timezones since it is unix based.

This is my aggregate function to get distinct values based on filters.

```
return await Model.aggregate(
        [
            {
                $match: filters
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {userUuid: "$userUuid" }
                    }
            }
        ]
    ).allowDiskUse(true);
```

As I said, $match does not work with moment, but only with new Date(opts.startDate), however, JavaScript's new Date disregards moment's timezone. Nor it has a proper native timezone. Any thought on how to achieve this array of unique ids based on filters with Mongoose?

Comment: You can try this - assign the value returned by `moment(opts.startDate).tz('America/Chicago').format()`  to a variable, and that value with the aggregation's `$match`.

Comment: I am not sure I understood you. But if you suggested to assign the moment value to a variable and to use that variable within $match filters, it does not work. It is the same result.

Comment: What is the `moment(opts.startDate).tz('America/Chicago').format()` returned value?

Comment: What is the `date` field''s type, as stored in the database?

Comment: So lets say if opts.startDate is equal to 2020-01-29, then moment will return '2020-01-29T00:00:00.000-06:00'. Note: -06:00 is the Chicago timezone from the UTC default which is used in MongoDB. If I use new Date(momentObject), this will delete the timezone as mentioned in the question.

Comment: `date` field type is Mongoose date which is the default one in MongoDB

Comment: (1) The types of the fields to be compared must be same. (2) You can also use [Aggregation Date Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#date-expression-operators) to transform the input date to the format you want (within the query itself). Note that to use aggregation operators within the `$match` stage - use with the `$expr` operator.

Comment: The `date` field is Mongoose model Date, hence default MongoDB date type. Secondly, can you please write me how would you write the whole aggregation query with filters for distinct values of userUuid?

Comment: There are two operators the `$dateFromParts` and `$dateFromString` - you can use one of them to get the date type (with required timezone) from the input _string_ date (assuming `opts.startDate` is a string).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with and it works pretty well regarding the performance. Use this solution for large dataset:

```
        let filters = {
            applicationUuid: opts.applicationUuid,
            impressions: { $gte: opts.impressions },
            $expr: {
                $and: [
                    {
                        $gte: [
                            '$date',
                            {
                                $dateFromString: {
                                    dateString: opts.startDate,
                                    timezone: 'America/Chicago',
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                    {
                        $lt: [
                            '$date',
                            {
                                $dateFromString: {
                                    dateString: opts.endDate,
                                    timezone: 'America/Chicago',
                                },
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        }

        return Model.aggregate([
                { $match: filters },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: '$userUuid',
                    },
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id: 0,
                        userUuid: '$_id',
                    },
                },
            ])
            .allowDiskUse(true)
```

Which will return a list of unique ids i.e.

```
[
  { userUuid: "someId" },
  { userUuid: "someId" }
]
```

Use the following method on small dataset which is more convenient:

```
let filters = {
    applicationUuid: opts.applicationUuid,
    impressions: {
      $gte: opts.impressions
    },
    date: {
      $gte: opts.startDate,
      $lte: opts.endDate
    }
  }

  return Model.distinct("userUuid", filters)
```

Which will return the following result:

```
[ "someId", "someOtherId" ]
```